# Elements of $E^{\times},\cdot$ of the quotient ring $E:= \frac{\mathbb{Z}_3[X]}{\langle x^2 + x + 2\rangle}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, cayley-table

Consider the field $E:= \frac{\mathbb{Z}_3[X]}{\langle x^2 + x + 2\rangle}$.
If I'm right the elements of the quotient ring can be found as: 
$$a_0 + a_1x + \langle x^2 + x + 2\rangle.$$
So we got the possibilities in $\mathbb{Z}_3$:
$$\{0,1,2,\beta, 1+\beta , 2+\beta, 2\beta, 1+2\beta ,2+2\beta \}.$$
Here $\beta = \overline{x} = x + \langle x^2 + x + 2\rangle$ is a root of $x^2 + x+2$.
(Correct me if my notation is wrong.)

So how do we get the elements of unit of $E^{\times},\cdot$. I assume $1$ is in it, but don't know how to calculate the other elements. With the elements, what would be the Cayley table of $E^{\times},\cdot$?

Other little question: we know that $\beta$ is a solution of $x^2 + x+2$, what is the other root?

Comment: As you are moding out an irreducible quadratic, the Vieta relations are the easiest way to find the other root (see Iefuneste's answer). When/if you learn more about finite fields and/or Galois theory, another method (that generalizes to more complicated situations) is to use the Frobenius automorphism: If $\beta$ is one root of an irreducible polynomial in $\Bbb{Z}_p[x]$, then $\beta^p$ is always another. Here $p=3$, and
$$\beta^3=\beta^2\cdot\beta=-(\beta+2)\beta=-\beta^2-2\beta=-\beta+2$$ is the other root. This can be used recursively, but observe that $(-\beta+2)^3$ brings back $\beta$.

Comment: And, yes, your notation is fine. Too many engineers/programmers (with an interest in coding theory and/or crypto) get stuck denoting $\beta$ by $x$, IMO hampering the development of their understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After I figured out how to proper multiplicate in a quotient ring via: [Constructing a multiplication table for a finite field](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1309954/constructing-a-multiplication-table-for-a-finite-field), I managed to find the unit elements by calculating every possible combination. I found for instance:
\begin{split}
\beta(1+\beta)& = x^2 + x + \langle x^2 + x + 2\rangle \\  
& =x^2 + x + \langle x^2 + x + 2\rangle + (0 + \langle x^2 + x + 2\rangle)\\
&= x^2 + x + \langle x^2 + x + 2\rangle + 2x^2+2x+4+ \langle x^2 + x + 2\rangle\\
&= 3x^2+ 3x +4 +\langle x^2 + x + 2\rangle\\
&=0+0+1+\langle x^2 + x + 2\rangle\\
&=1
\end{split}
If I do this for the other elements, I find that
$(2+\beta)(1+2\beta)=1$ and $(2\beta)(2+2\beta)=1$.

So the elements of unit become: $E^{\times},\cdot = \{1,\beta,1+\beta,2+\beta,1+2\beta,2\beta,2+2\beta\}$. The Cayley table is found by multiplying all the elements with each other. They are calculated similar as above.

Comment: $-1=2$ is missing from your list of elements of $E^*$. $E$ is a field, so all the $9-1$ non-zero elements are units.

Answer (score 1):

1) After line 1 you keep writing $x^2+x+1$ instead of  $x^2+x+2$ (and ditto for capital letters).

2) The other root of the equation $X^2+X+2=0$ is $2\beta +2$, in order that the sum $\beta+ (2\beta+2)$ of the roots of that equation be $2=-1$, the opposite of the coefficient of $X$.

Comment: Ddited the typos, my bad,  do you know how to calculate the elements of unit?

Comment: The invertible elements of $E$ ( which I suppose is what you mean by "elements of unit" ) are $E^{\times}=E\setminus \{0\}$, **an equality valid for any field**. (As mentioned by @Jyrki you forgot $2=-1$ in your description of that multiplicative group)

Comment: In your comment the first word of "Edited the typos" has a typo. I see the beginning of an interesting infinite recursion process...

Comment: Haha, I think I was possessed by the devil of typos back then